# Nested Table issue in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an issue in jquery mobile table.

i want to acheive the result like

[image: innertable_plain_html.png]

which i got from the Plain HTML  code

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>1941
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Rank</td>
                <td>1941</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

i want to achieve the same using jquery mobile table using data-role="table", data-mode="reflow".
When i did the same,

```
<table data-role="table" id="my-table-next" data-mode="reflow" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1941
      <table data-role="table" id="my-table-second" data-mode="columntoggle" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1941</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i resulted in :
[image: jqueryMobileTable]

was expecting the result as shown in the first image,

Please help me in this issue

Thanks in advance
Ravi.M

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I used tables without any data-roles for them, and they worked fine on jquery mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with SaurabhLP's view. This isn't a use case of using a table. And moreover, jQM tables dont support `rowspan` (which i think you'd use). Instead use gridviews. See the <kbd>[docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/grids/)</kbd>.

I've also set up a demo for you at <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/nenDP/)</kbd>.

This should give you a solid start.

I've used a lot of inline styles, you could move them to a stylesheet and make them work by adding a `!important;` attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use tables for this, use grid system for this it will be appropriate for flexible rows and columns, grid system will not issue for nested structure design for you:-

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/grids/

Thanks hope this help for you...